# How to catch mouse left button on mouseover event?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to catch when user press left button on mouse while hovering over cells in a html table using vanilla javascript. The purpose is to paint a cell in black when user is clicking with mouse while dragging (drawing like in MsPaint, when you draw a line for example)

I added an "over" event listener on each td of my table and used buttons property to check if left button is pressed or not:

```
celle = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
for (i=0;i<celle.length;i++)
celle[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function(e){
if(e.buttons == 1 ){
    e.target.style.backgroundColor="black";
}
})
```

This code works but not always and not perfectly. First it starts setting the background color of the next element, not the one on which I pressed the mouse. Moreover, sometimes it doesn't set any color at all (there is a small icon like "accessed denied" in Chrome's window). It appears to work quite randomly and unpredicatably.

I tried also with jQuery, but I found similar problems. Anyone can help me?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Split the problem into several parts. I would add a `mousedown` and `mouseup` eventlistener to the whole window and set a global state if you're currently drawing:

```
var drawState=false
window.addEventListener("mousedown",function(e){
if(e.button===1){
   drawState = true;
}});

window.addEventListener("mouseup",function(e){
if(e.button===1){
   drawState = false;
}});
```

You can improve the window listeners with some checks, if the mouse is over a cell.

After this you can add a `mouseenter` listener to all your cells. Mouseenter is only fired once you enter a cell and not on every move inside the element:

```
celle[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", function(e){
   if(drawState){
      e.target.style.backgroundColor="black";
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of tracking mouseover, track three events:

1. `mousemove` - to constantly get the mouse position
2. `mousedown` - to set the mouse state as currently clicked down
3. `mouseup` - to set the mouse state as currently released

It works this way:

1. `handleMousemove` constantly updates the mouse position and check mouse state
2. When the mouse is clicked down, `handleMousedown` is fired
3. `handleMousedown` set the state as 'down'
4. When `handleMousemove` sees that mouse state is 'down', it fires click event at the current mouse position
5. When the mouse is released, `handleMouseup` is fired
6. `handleMouseup` set the state as 'released' and everything returns to normal
7. Repeat

   ```
   var mouseIsDown = false;
   var mousePosition = { x:-1, y:-1 };

   let handleMousemove = (event) => {
       // get the mouse position
     mousePosition.x = event.x;
     mousePosition.y = event.y;
     if(mouseIsDown) // if mouse state is currently down, fire click at mouse position
     {
       let elem = document.elementFromPoint(mousePosition.x, mousePosition.y);
       // you can add some conditions before clicking
       if(something)
       {
         elem.click();
       }
     }
   };

   let handleMousedown = (event) => {
       mouseIsDown = true;
     // set the mouse state as 'down'
   };

   let handleMouseup = (event) => {
       mouseIsDown = false;
     // set the mouse state as 'release'
   };

   document.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMousemove);
   document.addEventListener('mousedown', handleMousedown);
   document.addEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseup);
   ```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Black3800/9wvh8bzg/5/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everybody for your kind answers. Proposed codes work almost ok. The only problem is that sometimes browser shows the NO SYMBOL cursor. Unfortunately I can't post an image but you can find it here:

[NO Symbol](http://www.clker.com/cliparts/u/1/R/3/S/V/no-symbol-skinny-th.png)

and the only way to keep on drawing is clicking outside the table and then clicking again inside.

This is my code:

```
var mouseIsDown = false;
var mousePosition = { x:-1, y:-1 };

let handleMousemove = (event) => {
    // get the mouse position
  mousePosition.x = event.x;
  mousePosition.y = event.y;
  if(mouseIsDown) // if mouse state is currently down, fire click at mouse position
  {
    let elem = document.elementFromPoint(mousePosition.x, mousePosition.y);
    // you can add some conditions before clicking
    if (event.buttons==1)
    {
      elem.click();
    }
  }
};

let handleMousedown = (event) => {
    mouseIsDown = true;
  // set the mouse state as 'down'
};

let handleMouseup = (event) => {
    mouseIsDown = false;
  // set the mouse state as 'release'
};

document.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMousemove);
document.addEventListener('mousedown', handleMousedown);
document.addEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseup);

celle = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
for (i=0;i<celle.length;i++)
celle[i].addEventListener("click", function(e){
        e.target.style.backgroundColor="black";
    }
)
```

Answer (score -3):

Isn't it easier to just add a listener for "click" ? If the element is clicked it also over the cell.

```
celle[i].addEventListener("click", function(e){
   e.target.style.backgroundColor="black";
}
```

Comment: This is not working while dragging with button pressed because click will just be fired after releasing the mousebutton.

Comment: Sorry I overlooked that part :)